# Bootstrap images not working?

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, icons

I have recently installed twitter bootstrap to my website and I have been developing with that. I recently read their tutorial on their icons/images. You can find the tutorial here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html under the "Images" section.

I tried using one of their examples:

```
<i class="icon-search"></i>
```

and no image showed up.

I have also tried:

```
<i class="icon-search"/>
```

This is probably a dumb question, im just very tired and I am having trouble thinking this through. I did not just try "icon-search" I also did other ones but nothing worked.

Any help would be great, thanks!

EDIT: Also my glyphicons are in img/glyphicons.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out. I did `<i class="icon-user"></i>` and it didn't work originally but then I saved my project and went out to take a walk and I came back and it was working. No clue what happened but I guess it was just a bug.